# How to display the "Information Tab" for vector tiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-tiles

I added a vector layer in QGIS and would like to see information about those vector tiles in QGis as described here:

[image]

https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector_tiles/vector_tiles_properties.html

I have no idea where to open this tab. The layer properties message box did not help me further.

My layer properties look ike this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on the vector layer in the layers menu and click properties (it is at the bottom). The top tab on the left is information.

[image: Information screenshot]

Comment: Also if  the layer is not loaded into QGIS you can access more or less the same information from the Data source Manager by activating the properties widget (click on the blue circle whth an "i" in it) the information display after you select a layer

Comment: Your layer properties dialog looks enhanced compared to mine, you have source, symbology and so. I added in image from mine above. Do you have an idea why that is different?

Comment: 1. what version of QGIS are you using? 2. What you are viewing is a web layer, not a local vector file.

Comment: I added a vector tiles connection pointing to an http server. I wonder why the source (file,web) makes a difference, in both cases QGis reads a file holding vector data (i am dealing with Mapbox vector tiles only, so that is always "webby")

Comment: I found it! Very confusingly there are 2 layer property dialogs. One that is opened with right click in thebrowser and another in the layers menu. the last one looks like in your screenshot.